# C: Trying to make a matrix of m*n random normal distributed numbers (Box muller 2 on polar form)

Tags: c, random

I'm trying to fill an `m x n` array with normally-distributed random numbers, where normally-distributed numbers are defined as seen in the code, where you first have to find two uniformly distributed numbers and r, to define 2 normally-distributed numbers. When I run the program it just prints the same two numbers over and over in the array, as if variable `rv_new` in the code just keeps being the same struct.

Here are the parts of the code that are supposed to generate and print the numbers.  I'm guessing that maybe the mistake has something to do with the `rejection_sampling()` function (is it stupid to make it as a struct?).

```
typedef struct rv rv;
struct rv {
    double v1;
    double v2;
    double r;
};

/*Function prototypes*/
double **malloc_array2d(size_t m, size_t n);
rv rejection_sampling(void);
void free_array2d(double ** B);

int main(void) {

    unsigned int m, n;
    double **A;

    ... (user input to get m and n)

    /*Dynamically allocate a m-by-n array of doubles*/
    A = malloc_array2d(m,n);
    if (A == NULL) {
        free_array2d(A);
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    //it is here I try to make the matrix: 
    for (int i = 0; i <= m * n - 1; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            rv rv_new = rejection_sampling();
            A[0][i] = rv_new.v1 * (sqrt(-2 * log(pow(rv_new.r, 2)))) / rv_new.r; 
            A[0][i+1] = rv_new.v2 * (sqrt(-2 * log(pow(rv_new.r, 2)))) / rv_new.r;      
        }
        else {;}
    }

    /*printing of the 2D-array with the m*n normally uniformly distributed numbers*/
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf(" %5.2f", A[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

/*Free memory and return*/
free_array2d(A);
return 0;

}

rv rejection_sampling(void) {    // Function that returns a struct containing a sample (v1,v2) and r
    double v1 = 0;
    double v2 = 0;
    double r = 0;
    double Randmax = RAND_MAX;

    srand(time(NULL));                               //Seed to the rand-function

    do {                                           
        v1 = rand() / Randmax;  //uniformly distributed random numbers between [0,1]
        v2 = rand() / Randmax;
        v1 = -1 + 2 * v1;      //uniformly distributed random numbers between [-1,1]
        v2 = -1 + 2 * v2;
        r = sqrt(pow(v1, 2) + pow(v2, 2));

    } while (r >= 1 || r == 0);

    rv new_rv;                                      //creates struct
    new_rv.v1 = v1;
    new_rv.v2 = v2;
    new_rv.r = r;

    return new_rv;
}

void free_array2d(double ** A){   
if ( A == NULL) return;
free(A[0]);                   
free(A);                      
return;
}

double ** malloc_array2d(size_t m, size_t n){    

double **A;
size_t i;

A = (double **) malloc(m*sizeof(double *));     
if (A == NULL)
    return NULL;

A[0]=(double *)malloc(m*n*sizeof(double));    
if ( A[0] == NULL) {
    free(A);
    return NULL;}

for(i = 1; i < m; i++)
    A[i]=A[0]+i*n;     
    return A;
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output and what is the actual output? Give an example of input.

Comment: The output I get is a m*n matrix that just consists of the same 2 random normal distributed numbers. I expect the output to be a m*n matrix with m*n random normal distributed numbers. The only input is just the size go the matrix, m and n. I am trying to make the Box muller transform on polar form, but i am not only supposed to make 2 random numbers, but m*n

Comment: Can you edit your question to include `malloc_array2d` and `free_array2d(A)` please?

Comment: Can you give an example of the matrix?

Comment: if for example i input m=3 and n=3 i get a matrix looking like this [-0.03,-1.84,-0.03;-1.84,-0.03,-1.84;-0.03,-1.84-0.03]  but what i really want is 9 different normally distributed numbers, where they pairwise are independently normally distributed.

Comment: what do you mean with *normally distributed numbers* ? are they distributed with a normal(0, 1), diferent mean, different standard dev?

Comment: oooh, I already fixed my problem - but yeah the user would have to input mean and variance too :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you call `srand(time(NULL));` *every* time you generate random numbers in your `rejection_sampling` function.

You need to move `srand(time(NULL));` to the start of your `main` function :)

**Explanation**

Imagine you have a list of "random" numbers, and every time you call `rand()` it gives you the value in the list, then moves onto the next value. The problem is that every time you run your program, you will get the same sequence of "random" numbers. The solution is to pick a "random" starting position in that list - which is "seeding" - generally done by using the current time. What you are inadvertently doing, is resetting to the same position in this "random" list every time you want a random numbers, so you will get the same values (per second at least).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it goes too fast and `srand(time(NULL));` gives you always the same seed. Try giving a feed-back to `rejection_sampling` like this

```
rv rejection_sampling(int feedback){ //This feedback could be the i in your loop
    // ...
    srand(time(NULL)+feedback);
```

Or simply seed the random before loop and don't seed it again